# How to replace the method with Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, java-8

It can be an obvious question but I am thinking how to replace the method below with java 8 streams.

```
private String assembleString(int numberOfCharacters, char character) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCharacters; i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(character);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

I am new in Java, so java 8 it is like an unexplored world for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you even want to introduce Streams to something this simple? Please don't use Streams for the sake of it.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul it is always easier to learn something with the simplest way first, he seems trying to learn something.

Comment: Please keep in your mind that streams are not faster/better by default. Do not use them just "because its fancy java 8"...

Comment: @Al-Mothafar I'd start with simple List/Map/Collection manipulation as shown in all the tutorials, not padding a String, for which the creation of Stream related objects is overkill and doesn't necessarily lead to better or more readable code. To clean up the posted code, I would use a library such as Commons StringUtils instead of Streams "just because I can".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is just `Collections.nCopies`

```
private static String assembleString(int numberOfCharacters, char character) {
    return String.join("",
            Collections.nCopies(numberOfCharacters, String.valueOf(character))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Stream.generate`:

```
return Stream.generate(() -> String.valueOf(character))
              .limit(numberOfCharacters)
              .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

or `IntStream.rangeClosed`:

```
return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numberOfCharacters)
                .mapToObj(n -> String.valueOf(character))
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 2):

This should suffice.

```
IntStream.range(0, numberOfCharacters)  
  .mapToObj(value -> character)
  .forEach(stringBuilder::append);
```

**EDIT:**

Taking Holger's suggestion, this would be even more functional and cleaner.

```
IntStream.range(0, numberOfCharacters) 
  .map(value -> character) .collect(StringBuilder::new, 
     StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append);
```

Comment: +1 for the cleanest Streams based implementation on this page - it's the only one that doesn't create superfluous Strings on the way.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul even cleaner would be `.map(value -> character) .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)` instead of `.mapToObj(value -> character) .forEach(stringBuilder::append)` to an existing `StringBuilder`. It would also avoid boxing into `Character` objects.

Comment: shoudn't it be `forEachOrdered` ?

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc when we are just appending the same character n number of times, it doesn't matter whether  it is ordered or not isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IntStream`:

```
private String assembleString(int numberOfCharacters, char character) {
        return IntStream.range(0, numberOfCharacters)
               .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(character)).collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 11+, you could also use [`String::repeat`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)):

```
return String.repeat(Character.toString(character), numberOfCharacters);
```

Or you could "steal" their implementation:

```
char[] repeated = new char[numberOfCharacters];
Arrays.fill(repeated, character);
return new String(repeated);
```

Comment: `Arrays.fill(…)` also was the first thing that came into my mind. Of course, an implementation within `String` itself, like `repeat` avoids the defensive copying of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Just for "completeness", without apparent loops or Streams:

```
private String assembleString(int numberOfCharacters, char character) {
    return new String(new char[numberOfCharacters]).replace('\0', character);
}
```

How: Creates a new char array of size 'numberOfCharacters', which will be initialised with 'null' characters. Construct a String from this array, then replace all occurrences of the null character with the desired one.